# Issue with using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I was creating project in Angular and to format date I decided to use moment.js. But the problem is from the backend I get such format "2020-02-06" thus I decided to use 'MMM DD, YYYY' and I want "2020-02-06" to look like Feb 6, 2020 with this format MMM DD, YYYY. So, to achieve that I have this code

```
moment(
                                    response.data.projectCreatedDate //this contains "2020-02-06"
                                ).format("MMM DD, YYYY");
```

BUT the problem is instead of getting Feb 6, 2020 I get 13 May, 2020 which is today's date. Pls can you help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment with `empty` argument returns `current date`, and format on top of it returns `current formatted date` .Your date from server might be `undefined`, Hence you are the getting `current date` formatted.
You can also pass custom date for formatting too!

```js
//Formatting an input date
var str = "2020-02-06";
console.log(moment(str, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MMM D,YYYY"));

//Formatting current date
console.log('Current Date: ', moment().format("MMM D,YYYY"));

//Formatting array of dates
var arr = ["2020-02-06", "2020-01-13"];
var res = arr.map(date => {
  return moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MMM D,YYYY");
});
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry I turns out that I have an array of dates and I want to format each date in array with MMM D,YYYY. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with moment here, you are getting an empty response inside response.data.projectCreatedDate from your server.

```
moment("2020-02-06").format("MMM DD, YYYY") //Feb 06, 2020
moment().format("MMM DD, YYYY") //todays date.
```

Thanks.